# UI text not updating

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface

I know, so many of people have asked this question. I have gone to all of those posts, and none of the solutions have solved my problem. i am creating a level progress bar , here in this script i am trying to update text (levelNumber) and add +1 to levelNumber every time level is completed, here i am using playerprefs to save levelNumber so data can passes through next levels(scenes). but problem is levelNumber not even updating in Text field , as per script Text_1 should start from 0 and Text_2 from 1 when game starts its showing values which i have given in inspector 1 and 2. to confirm that i have changed values in inspector to 21 and 30 again when game starts its showing 21 and 30. that means UI Text not updating from script .

```
public class PrograssBar : MonoBehaviour
{
 [SerializeField] private Text Text_1;
 [SerializeField] private Text Text_2;
 private int levelNumber = 0;
 [SerializeField] Transform startTransform;
 Transform finishTransform;
 [SerializeField] Slider slider;

 float maxDistance;


 void OnEnable()
 {
     levelNumber = 0;
 }

 void Start()
 {
     finishTransform = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("CloneGoal").GetComponent<Transform>();
     maxDistance = getDistance();
     levelNumber = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("LevelNumber");

 }


 void Update()
 {
     if (startTransform.position.z <= maxDistance)
     {
         float distance = 1 - (getDistance() / maxDistance);
         setProgress(distance);
     }

 }

 float getDistance()
 {

     return Vector3.Distance(startTransform.position, (finishTransform.position - new Vector3(0, 0, 22)));
 }


 void setProgress(float p)
 {
     slider.value = p;
 }

 private void LevelUp()
 {
     UpdateLevel(levelNumber + 1);
     PlayerPrefs.SetInt("LevelNumber", levelNumber);
 }

 private void UpdateLevel(int levelNumber)
 {
     this.levelNumber = levelNumber;
     Text_1.text = " " +this.levelNumber.ToString();
     Text_2.text = " " +(this.levelNumber + 1).ToString();
 }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you never save your `levelNumber` to prefs during your execution, so your `LevelUp` function should look like:

```
private void LevelUp()
{
     UpdateLevel(levelNumber + 1);
     PlayerPrefs.SetInt("LevelNumber", levelNumber);
     PlayerPrefs.Save();
}
```

See this [doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.Save.html)

Comment: Thank you , actually playerprefs working fine but problem is levelNumber not even updating in Text field , as per script Text_1 should start from 0 and Text_2 from 1 when game starts but its showing values which i have given in inspector 1 and 2. to confirm that i have changed values in inspector to 21 and 30 again when game starts its showing 21 and 30. that means UI Text not updating from script

Answer (score 0):

In the method `private void UpdateLevel(int level)` you're setting `this.levelNumber = levelNumber`.
And the attribute of a method is `int level`.
So you might want to do:

```
this.levelNumber = level;
```

And I'm not quite sure where you're calling the method `private void LevelUp()` since it's private and it's not called anywhere inside this class.

Comment: I am sorry actually i used as level instead of levelNumber in my script but i have changed here to levelNumber,so i thought you understand better . my mistake i forgot to changed that level to levelNumber , so its not working

Comment: Did you try to log this? Log LevelUp and UpdateLevel methods and print values from these methods, maybe they're not even called/triggered

Comment: i didnt try log but every time when i finished level for a fraction of second Text fields showing values from script, after loading next scene again values changed to whatere value i put in inspector . i dont understand whats happening